# how to run android studio application with adb wifi on ubutu18

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

i want run android studio applcation with adb wifi on ubuntu.
this is error mmessage:
"
Unable to connect to device 'R17B2502570 no permissions (user in plugdev group; are your udev rules wrong?); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] usb:1-1 transport_id:8'. Make sure that your computer and your device are connected to the same WiFi network.
"
pls help me

Answer (score 0):

you need to link the connection.

with your device connected via usb, type in your ubuntu terminal:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

then:

```
adb connect <YOUR_DEVICE_IP>:5555
```

so, you can unplug your usb and the Android Studio will recognize your device.

**your computer and your device must be connected to the same WiFi